# How to remove '/' from the string?

Tags: python

I have a problem with the backslash. When the code executes numbers from the text file it looks like this 00744/,00474/ ...

And when I tried to float string into integer I got TypeErro: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str'.

How I can remove '/' from the numbers?
Thank you

Comment: Can you share the code please ?

Comment: How anyone can help you without seeing your source code?

Comment: `/` is a forward slash, not a backslash.

Comment: If you just want to remove the `/`, you can use `replace`: `stringvar.replace("/", "")` reference:https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_replace.asp

Comment: `your_var = re.sub(r'\/','','00744/,00474/')`

Comment: You may think about [accepting an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to reward those how helped you, or at least comment to explain what's missing ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a string and want to remove chars at the end from it, you can use `str.rstrip()` with custom characters

```
content = "123/"
print(content.rstrip("/")) # 123

content = "123=/"
print(content.rstrip("/"))      # 123=
print(content.rstrip("/=-_()")) # 123
```

Then convert to int

```
int("00474/".rstrip("/"))  # 474
```

Answer (score 0):

You can you regex `re.sub` to remove all the backslash.

```
a = '00744/,00474/,today/'
import re
a = re.sub(r'(?<=\d)\/','',a)
print (a)
```

The output of this will be:

```
00744,00474,today/
```

This will ensure that all backslash removed are only for digits and not for characters.

Comment: You can avoid importing `re` by using `str.replace()`

Comment: @mpm, unfortunately str.replace() will not solve it the way i am looking for